# Problem with context processor in async django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

My django app has following features:

1. A model with an async method.
2. An async view.
3. A context processor that call an async method from the model and modifies the response context from the view.

I am using Django 5.0 and python 3.12, daphne as asgi server.

What's my problem:
It appears that as of now django does not differentiate between sync and async context processors. From django source (`django/template/context.py`):

```
updates = {}
for processor in processors:
  context = processor(self.request)
  print(f"Context processor {processor.__qualname__}")
  try:
    updates.update(context)
    except TypeError as e:
      raise TypeError(
        f"Context processor {processor.__qualname__} didn't return a " "dictionary."
      ) from e
```

So if a context processor is async, django internals will just try to update response context with a coroutine and cause a `Context processor ... didn't return a dictionary.` exception.

So I tried to make my context processor synchronous by wrapping a call to the async model method with `asgiref.sync.async_to_sync`.
Regardless of setting the `force_new_loop` parameter I am getting `You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.` exception.

Am I missing something or is django async support just not at the point where it can provide the same functionality as sync one?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue today and you're correct: context processors don't support async (yet!).

I believe it's this specific line that needs to be made async-aware:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/b47bdb4cd9149ee2a39bf1cc9996a36a940bd7d9/django/template/context.py#L254C23-L254C32

`context = processor(self.request)`
where `processor` is the actual context processor function.

I've created a thread on the Django forums to discuss this: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/async-context-processors/27935